# Agrupar celdas de una tabla mediante CSS utilizando una única imagen de fondo

Tags: html, css

Seguramente haya una forma sencilla de hacer lo que quiero pero no termino de visualizarla.

Mi idea es crear un generador de banderas utilizando únicamente CSS. A base de selectores no tengo problemas en poner los colores base de las banderas pero me ha surgido una duda con cómo poner los escudos de dichas banderas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, en esta bandera de España quisiera poner el escudo. Para ello he seleccionado los `td` de las posiciones donde iría y le he puesto el `background-image`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente esto pone un `background` a cada `td` pero me gustaría saber si existe alguna propiedad `CSS` que permita agrupar dichas celdas y aplicar un único fondo a esa agrupación

Otra opción que se me había ocurrido es poner la imagen de fondo a una única celda y hacer que se salga por tamaño de dicha celda.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Aquí dejo lo que tengo ahora mismo:

```css
/*SPANISH-FLAG*/
.sp-flag tr:nth-last-child(-n+4) td{
  background-color: #C60B1E;
  color: #C60B1E;
}
.sp-flag tr:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+4) td{
  background-color: #C60B1E;
  color: #C60B1E;
}
.sp-flag tr:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+9) td{
  background-color: #FFC400;
  color: #FFC400;
}

.sp-flag tr:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+9) td:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+9){
  color: transparent;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Escudo_de_Espa%C3%B1a_%28mazonado%29.svg/200px-Escudo_de_Espa%C3%B1a_%28mazonado%29.svg.png");
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flags.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="flag" class="flag sp-flag">
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Edito**

Haciendo pruebas he dado con la solución que comentaba como segunda opción. Lo que he hecho ha sido poner la imagen de fondo a un único `td` y hacer un `transform: scale(4.5)` para agrandarla. De todas formas dejo la pregunta como abierta porque me parece una solución un poco "chapucera" y me gustaría algo más elegante si puede ser:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Impact;
}

.flag tr td{
  background-color: white;
  color:white;
}
.flag tr:first-child td{
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
.flag tr:last-child td{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.flag tr td:first-child{
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
.flag tr td:last-child{
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

/*SPANISH-FLAG*/
.sp-flag tr:nth-last-child(-n+4) td{
  background-color: #C60B1E;
  color: #C60B1E;
}
.sp-flag tr:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+4) td{
  background-color: #C60B1E;
  color: #C60B1E;
}
.sp-flag tr:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+9) td{
  background-color: #FFC400;
  color: #FFC400;
}

.sp-flag tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(5){
  color: transparent;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Escudo_de_Espa%C3%B1a_%28mazonado%29.svg/200px-Escudo_de_Espa%C3%B1a_%28mazonado%29.svg.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: scale(4.5);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Fun with flags!</h1>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="flag" class="flag sp-flag">
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se puede alterar el HTML?

Comment: Preferiría no hacerlo porque quería utilizar ese HTML como "lienzo" único para todas las banderas que genere. La idea es intentar hacerlo sólo con CSS (si es posible).

Comment: Puedes unirlas con colspan y rowspan

Comment: Para eso necesito cambiar el HTML y me gustaría no hacerlo.

Comment: Ajuro tenemos que usar los td? puedo usar otra solucion en css que no sea aplicable a los tds?

Comment: Si no modifica el HTML ni añade JS, adelante.

Comment: no es por molestar pero tu solución a base de `html table` es horrible de implementar, horrible de mantener, horrible de hacerlo dinámico. Quizás va a ser tiempo perdido pero te recomiendo desechar esta solución hacer esto con svg o canvas y hay cientos de librerías para svg y canvas que te pueden ayudar

Comment: No me molesta. El HTML no es idea mía, está copiado de aquí (https://codepen.io/estelle/full/pVzYRZ) y precisamente está pensado así para aprender a usar selectores (especialmente nth-child, first-of-type, etc.). El objetivo es mejorar en mi conocimiento de CSS y no tiene que ser ninguna solución a nada (con que me sirva para mejorar en CSS  es más que suficiente :)). Evidentemente, si quisiera implementar algo real no lo haría así ;)

Answer (score 0):

Para el ejemplo de la bandera de **España** sería agregar **colspan** y **rowspan**, a la **cuarta** columna de la fila **5**.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="flag" class="flag sp-flag">
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td colspan="6" rowspan="5"></td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

También necesitas adaptar los selectores **CSS** para que sólo se aplique el escudo a la celda necesaria.

```
.sp-flag tr:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+5) td:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+4)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero insisto en que me gustaría conseguirlo sin tocar el HTML. Si no es posible tendré que hacerlo así pero me gustaría saber si tengo alguna opción de hacerlo sólo con CSS.